# Save a variable when the server is off

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

In fact I am making a Minecraft plugin and I was wondering how some plugins (without using DB) manage to keep information even when the server is off.

For example if we make a grade plugin and we create a different list or we stack the players who constitute each. When the server will shut down and restart afterwards, the lists will become empty again (as I initialized them).

So I wanted to know if anyone had any idea how to keep this information.

Answer (score 0):

If a plugin want to save informations only for itself, and it don't need to make it accessible from another way (a PHP website for example), you can use YAML format.

1. Create the config file :

```
File usersFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "user-data.yml");
if(!usersFile.exists()) { // don't exist
    usersFile.createNewFile();
    // OR you can copy file, but the plugin should contains a default file
    /*try (InputStream in = plugin.getResource("user-data.yml");
                         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(usersFile)) {
        ByteStreams.copy(in, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}
```

2. Load the file as Yaml content :

```
YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(usersFile);
```

3. Edit content :

```
config.set(playerUUID, myVar);
```

4. Save content :

```
config.save(usersFile);
```

Also, I suggest you to make I/O async (read & write) with scheduler.

Bonus:

If you want to make ONE config file per user, and with default config, do like that :

```
File oneUsersFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), playerUUID + ".yml");
if(!oneUsersFile.exists()) { // don't exist
    try (InputStream in = plugin.getResource("my-def-file.yml");
                         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(oneUsersFile)) {
        ByteStreams.copy(in, out); // copy default to current
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
YamlConfiguration userConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(oneUsersFile);
```

PS: the variable `plugin` is the instance of your plugin, i.e. the class which extends "JavaPlugin".

Answer (score 0):

You can use PersistentDataContainers:
To read data from a player, use

```java
PersistentDataContainer p = player.getPersistentDataContainer();
int blocksBroken = p.get(new NamespacedKey(plugin, "blocks_broken"), PersistentDataType.INTEGER); // You can also use DOUBLE, STRING, etc.
```

The Namespaced key refers to the name or pointer to the data being stored. The PersistentDataType refers to the type of data that is being stored, which can be any Java primitive type or String. To write data to a player, use

`p.set(new NamespacedKey(plugin, "blocks_broken"), PersistentDataType.INTEGER, blocksBroken + 1);`